# java как корректно вкинуть ArithmeticExeption при делении на 0

Tags: java, округление

подскажите, как дооформить таск, чтобы отрабатывал проброс ошибок и return в случае корректного вычисления (b!=0)? Если я понимаю правильно, то при делении положительного на 0 должно быть Infinity, отрицательного -Infinity, 0 на 0 -- NaN. но при попытке округлить Infinity округляется.

```
public class test {
public static int precision = 3;
public static double a = -2.34567;
public static double b = 0;

public static double div(double a, double b, int precision) throws IOException {

    try {
        double res = a / b;
        double resRound = Math.round(res * Math.pow(10, precision)) / Math.pow(10, precision);

    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("ArithmeticException");
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double res = a / b;
if (Double.isNaN(res) || Double.isInfinite(res)) {
  throw new ArithmeticException("...");
}
return Math.round(res * Math.pow(10, precision)) / Math.pow(10, precision);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это тот самый случай, когда ты понимаешь что задача довольно проста, но опыта нехватает.

Answer (score -2):

```
try {
    double res = a / b;
    double resRound = Math.round(res * Math.pow(10, precision)) / Math.pow(10, precision);

} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    res=0; //здесь можно что-то другое
    System.out.println("ArithmeticException");
}
return res;
```

Comment: return res; простите, мне бы хотелось получать return double resRound;

Comment: Ну так подставьте вместо res любую другую переменную double

Comment: Переменная объявленая в блоке try видна только в блоке try. в блоке catch ее быть неможет. подставить просто, знать бы что и куда.

Comment: Объявите переменную до блока try. Дерзайте. Пробуйте

Comment: да, но тогда Infinity округляется до 9Ехзчего-тотам. Если бы я нашел решение, то не задавал бы вопрос. задача не такая простая как кажется на первый взгляд(покрайней мере пока я не знаю на нее ответа).